# Como personalizar un mensaje de error en mysql?

Tags: mysql

*Me gustaria saber como hacer para que no se imprima el error de clave duplicada y evitar que se muestre informacion de mis tablas, usando un mensaje personalizado *

## codigo

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
    PROCEDURE `insertarclientes`(
         in nombre varchar(20),
         apellido varchar(20), 
         num_cedula varchar(20),
         direccion varchar(20),
         telefono varchar(20),
         email varchar(20)
        )
BEGIN

insert into persona values (idpersona,nombre,apellido,num_cedula,direccion,telefono,email);

END
```

Comment: Desde MySQL 5 puedes usar [`SIGNAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html), en el Manual de referencia explican varios casos de uso, también [aquí tienes un tutorial sencillo y claro](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-signal-resignal/) que explica cómo funciona.

Comment: Como solución capture el error en netbeans  mediante un try/catch y evite que se muestren las relaciones de mis tablas. No encontre otra solucion

Comment: Debiste haber dicho que estabas trabajando con Java. Yo interpreté que querias hacerlo desde MySQL directamente.